# Kernel Restarts upon failing(?) to import tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I've recently updated my Anaconda environment, and now I can't import tensorflow anymore. Everytime I run a script containing it, the Spyder Console runs for a while, then just stops and resets to ln[1].

I tried to see how far the script compiles, and it does everything fine, until the import statement. Weirdly enough, the autocomplete still works for tf, which means that my installation should be fine. Reinstalling tensorflow also didn't do anything.

There are no error messages, because the compiler dies a silent death everytime I run the script. I've seen others describe a similar problem on a Jupyter, but their fixes didn't work. (Running the script without Spyder just freezes Python) 
I'd greatly appreciate help

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I did some black mathmagic and fixed it. What I did was reducing the tensorflow version via pip (to 1.14, but I don't think that matters) and then upgrading my entire conda set up again with conda update --all. I have no idea why, and the anaconda console screamed like it was tortured during the entire update, but now it works and I don't think I'll touch it again. If I see better fix, or if I encounter problems with this one, I'll update this post again.